# Is there significance that Dr.Strange saw 14M possibilities?

Tags: analysis, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

**WARNING**: this question contains (minor) spoilers for the Avengers: Infinity War.

In the *Avengers: Infinity War*, Dr. Strange mentioned that he have seen approximately 14 million possibilities that could be played out. (I couldn't recall the exact number.) Is this specific 14 million-ish number a reference to something, maybe in the comics? Or is it just an arbitrarily picked number?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is this specific 14 million-ish number a reference to something, maybe in the comics? Or is it just an arbitrarily picked number?

**14,000,605** to be exact!

And no, AFAIK, this number is completely arbitrary and has no significant meaning beyond the film (with the only meaning within the film being: they have a really, really, really small chance of succeeding).

1/14,000,605 * 100 = **0.000007% chance of success**, assuming the future doesn't change in a way that conflicts with Dr. Strange's initial foresights.

*The % chance of success reads as, "seven one millionths of one percent".*

Comment: I read an interesting theory that nothing Strange says or does after looking to the future can be trusted to be true, but merely to be what is on a path to success. He may have not actually seen that many possibilities but for some reason telling that to Tony was something that leads to a successful outcome.

Answer (score 4):

When Dr. Strange says that. It is to help cement the idea of how strong Thanos is. And how improbable it is that they beat him. Apart from that 1 in 14,000,605 chance.

I think this is why Strange gave Thanos the time stone so easily, despite saying to Ironman that he will protect it even if it meant the death of Tony and Peter.

This could mean that the one way to win or maybe undo all of this. It could be that otherwise some events that needs to happen won't happen. for example Fury contacting Captain Marvel.

Answer (score -1):

We know Dr. Strange doesn't just put up made-up numbers. There has to be some logic behind it.

Let's suppose there is just one superhero in this universe. The possibilities are: win/lose = 2.

But here, we have more than 24 superheroes, which means 2^24, approximately 16 million possibilities.

However, we know that Dr. Strange can't see futures after he has died, so 14,000,605 might be the one where they win, but he needs to virtually die, and also the one where Tony needs to live.

Comment: How does the number of super heros involved correlate to any given course of action's chance of success?

Comment: Your last sentence doesn't make sense, if he can't see past his death, then how would he know it was a winning outcome?

Answer (score -1):

14,000,605*100=0،0000007
Look out:have you noticed something

The code contains Seven numbers(six zeros+one six)
It means that there are Seven original avengers characters who have chance to save the world from thanos: iron man.captain America.thor.Hulk.Hawkeye.black widow.
Loki. Because they have more expérience with villains.
Captain marvel .ant man.black panther.guardians just are new avengers.and maybe they let original avengers finish what they have Begin in phase 1.this why doctor strange Said it's the end game.and phase 4 will be opened for the new characters

Comment: This is an interesting theory but what is the basis for it?

Comment: I don't count 7 numbers anywhere in that equation. Not in number of digits, nor unique numerals... what are you referring to?

Answer (score -1):

Ok I think it could be the day the trailer comes out, I was wondering why dr strange said 14,000,605 possible outcomes I was like why did they choose that number then I got to thinking if u go on marvels website they have a count down which is at 156 days something hours something minutes and something seconds if I’m right then at exactly 140 days 00 hours 06 minutes and 05 seconds will be when they release the trailer which if u don’t get what I’m saying is without the time units is 14,000,605 ‍♂️ which falls on December 13th, which also happens to be the release date of the new Spider-Man movie, making it very easy to add a trailer before or after the movie.

[image]

Comment: "140 days 00 hours 06 minutes and 05 seconds" - from when?

Comment: There is a count down clock for when Avengers 4 Annihilation comes out and so when the clock says 140 days 00 hours 06 min and 05 seconds will be when i think the trailer comes out, although this is a far reach, the numbers match up exactly to Dr. Strange’s number of possibilities he gave which was 14,000,605